# How to get back windows 10 boot loader after uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu a few months ago now I had to uninstall it die to some reason but I forgot to install windows boot loader and restarted the pc. It is showing a black screen how to boot again with windows 10.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

- On another computer
  [Create Bootable USB for Install Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).
  If you have previously created a
  [Recovery Drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-create-recovery-drive-windows-10-a.html),
  use it instead.
- Boot the USB on your computer and
  [Run Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).